# Discussion on recommendation / menu bar reverse engineering

Tags: discussion, site-scope, close-reasons

I wanted to have a short discussion on one question that looks problematic in terms of scope:

- [Modifying the Menu Bar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302285/modifying-the-menu-bar)

If you look at the initial version, it had a generally problematic closing which I've edited out.

> I'm not looking for a just specific answer (although that would be nice), I just need any information regarding the menu bar at all that would help lead me to my goal. Thanks.

The problem with that is that it acknowledges that this will be a discussion magnet / me too magnet / and makes it seem not a practical question that should have an actual answer that can be voted upon.

I do see how it could cover just about all the things we ask for in an off-site recommendation question. It clearly documents what is needed, what level of detail is needed, Apple may provide this documentation and anyone who knows how / where Apple provides this will knock that answer out of the "ballpark" so to say. Third party writers may also have documented this in a book or a blog post, so there's a good change this knowledge is out there.

My main reason for listing this is it sure seems like a Code Level question / framework programming question and runs afoul of our long established site scope to not host "programming" questions here. If this is a good recommendation question and it's really in the end about programming, it should probably go to Stack Overflow, no? I hesitate to migrate it since I don't know how well received it might be if it lands there without more code in the question.

If anyone has strong opinions and needs to cast close votes - I wanted to discuss it here whether it stays open or gets closed since I think this is a really good example we can hold up on where the line between scripting and documentation and code level questions are for the site.

Comment: The OP has 1 question at the beginning (looking for the location of the files) and another question at the end (book or document about the code).  The question could be read "I need help with my code" or "I'm looking for feature documentation so I can code".  This could be read as off-topic, I believe, if you think the core of the question is the OP wants coding help.  I just don't get that from the question, though.  My reading is they're looking for a resource the same way someone wants a book recommendation on Automator scripts.